# I am getting error while trying to resample unevenly spaced time series

Tags: python

If I have a timeseries stored in CSV with two columns with name- Date and WL. How do I call the time series to execute Traces library?

I used the following:

```
def parse_iso_datetime(value): return datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

import traces

ts = traces.TimeSeries.from_csv(r"D:/Consultancy Hatch/Flood assessment study Bangladesh/24092020/DATA_BWDB/WaterLevel/WL/Personal datasets_Karan/Time series_Freelancing.csv", time_column=0, time_transform=parse_iso_datetime, value_column=1,value_transform=int,default=0)
```

And got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-3341837aa25f>", line 1, in <module>
    ts = traces.TimeSeries.from_csv(r"D:/Consultancy Hatch/Flood assessment study Bangladesh/24092020/DATA_BWDB/WaterLevel/WL/Personal datasets_Karan/Time series_Freelancing.csv", time_column=0,
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traces\timeseries.py", line 821, in from_csv
    time = time_transform(row[time_column])
  File "<ipython-input-7-af8a296cea7f>", line 2, in parse_iso_datetime
    return datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you consider to `import datetime` to be able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Error says 'datetime' is not defined.
You haven't specified which version of python or datetime you are using, but lets say you use the one that comes from python 3.5.x onwards

you must import it and later call it properly, see the edited code snippet below:

```
import datetime
import traces


def parse_iso_datetime(value): 
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")


ts = traces.TimeSeries.from_csv(r"D:/Consultancy Hatch/Flood assessment study Bangladesh/24092020/DATA_BWDB/WaterLevel/WL/Personal datasets_Karan/Time series_Freelancing.csv", time_column=0, time_transform=parse_iso_datetime, value_column=1,value_transform=int,default=0)
```

Comment: This worked well. However, I got another error.                                                                   
ValueError: time data '98-6-16:0:0' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'

Comment: Try using time instead:

`import time ;
return time.strftime('_%y%m%d%H%M', time.localtime())`